# Running electronics bought in USA in the Uk?

Tags: variable

Ive got this power supply for a nintendo switch that was purchased in USA that i want to run in the UK.

On the back of the power supply (see image below) is says 100-240v. Apart from using a plug convertor is there anything else i would need to do ?

I notice on the power supply it says "see instruction manual for use in countries other than the USA" but i dont have the manual unfortunately.

[image: power supply]

Comment: That should work just fine because of the compatibility of the 60Hz voltage frequency in the US and 50Hz in the UK. The UK also has 240V for their voltage as well. If you're super curious about a cheat sheet of voltages and frequencies by country, [look here!](http://www.school-for-champions.com/science/ac_world_volt_freq_list.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's whats called a universal switching power supply. It handles both US and UK standard voltage and frequency. It will handle being used in the UK with a simple physical travel adapter.

Comment: Thanks @passerby for my future reference what identifies it as a universal switching power supply ? Also what do you think the manual might say about using it abroad ?

Comment: The input voltage and frequency. It covers like 90 percent of the world voltage standards.

Comment: @user27511 Warranty is not covered in other countries. Interface with an old style TV is probably out too.